# Need recommendation for Project Management software

Tags: windows, project-management

I used MS Project before and Gantt Project. And now I'm looking for free software.
What I need is simply do the Gantt Chart, and link with resources.  So that I can know which teammate is avialable or not.

however, one key feature I need is to have allow me to assign task on a person by hours, not by day.  That's why I have to drop Gantt Project because it is by date.

also, it would be nice if I can have multiple project shows on the same sheet.

Too bad that I can't use MS Project.  I don't mind if it is online or desktop, as long as it is quick and responsive and interactive.  (I found most of the online one is not that interactive).

Would anyone please give me some suggestions?  thanks. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looked at [OpenProj](http://openproj.org/openproj) ?

Comment: I find that OpenProj is kinda buggy. I tried setting the start date but it always bounces back to current date.   weird.

Comment: i restart OpenProj and now all work fine. :)  i like it

Comment: The links seems to be dead and the site will be coming back soon. 
I assume that this [openproj](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openproj/) project on sourceforge is the same project?! The [ProjectLibre](http://www.projectlibre.org/about) may also be a fit; according to wikipedia it is a fork of OpenProj

Answer (score 5):

I would use Gantter's Google Docs add-on. A full demo is located at https://app.gantter.com/

From this screenshot, when zoomed-in you can track by the hour. The project is free, but hints at a cost after beta.

[image]

Comment: thanks.  a good tool.  i m using it for my another project now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your requirements [Tom's Planner](http://tomsplanner.com/) might work for you:

> Tom's Planner is online Gantt chart software that allows anyone to
>   create, collaborate and share Gantt Charts online with drag and drop
>   simplicity. It's web based, extremely intuitive and easy-to-use. Watch
>   the quick tour or try Tom's Planner for free (no registration
>   required).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your needs I would recommend you to try [RationalPlan](http://www.rationalplan.com/) suite BUT it is NOT free. The [Multi Project](http://www.rationalplan.com/multi-project-management-software.php) version will also give you the possibility to work with multiple projects.

Comment: Made it clear with "now I'm looking for free software".

Answer (score 0):

[WORKetc](http://www.worketc.com/) is a suite of business management tools, but emphasizes project management and collaboration. The software covers everything from leads, sales automation, and contact organization, to invoices, projects, collaboration, support, and marketing. Because of this, managing projects becomes a lot simpler and faster.

Taking a gantt chart view of a project and its sub projects for example:

[image]

As you can see you can easily associate items together and manage packages of items rather than everything separately, and this can save a heck of a lot of time.